# Not sure how to form an SQL Query for the mentioned task

Tags: php, sql

I basically have a search box where the user types in something and the values are sent to another PHP file via GET and I am to search for the value in 2 different columns and print all the results.

```
  $search_for= $_GET['search'];
         $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT name,location FROM answers
                                WHERE name LIKE "%:variable%" OR
                                WHERE location LIKE "%:variable%"');
 $stmt->execute([':variable' => $search_for ]);
```

I used Distinct, in case there are repeated answers, I don't want to print them more than twice. Also, I am unsure whether the "%:variable%" part of the code is the problem.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT name,location,` < that trailing comma shouldn't be there.

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner Sorry that was a typo. Is that the only issue?

Comment: Now that you've changed the question/code, it may not be only that. I'd start by enabling error reporting *and* PDO exceptions. That way, you'll see what the errors are and may eventually lead you to a solution, besides the new answer given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several error .. remove the comma before FROM, use just one where,  use concat for form the like condition properly  (not `"%:variable%"` )  and last use use two binding param then you should pass  two values

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT name,location
                        FROM answers
                        WHERE name LIKE concat("%", :variable1, "%") OR
                            location LIKE concat("%", :variable2, "%")');

$stmt->execute([':variable1' => $search_for,  ':variable2' => $search_for]);
```